# Passing custom List of data using Bundle

Tags: android, list, android-fragments, bundle, custom-object

I'm developing a simple app, that contains tabview with fragment. I am stuck at the place, where i have to pass data to my newly created fragment on tabselect.

I have a List of  lists of my custom class objects:

```
List<List<NewsObjectClass>> myList;
```

Here is where I got stuck:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment{

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


    public PlaceholderFragment(){       

    }


    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber, List<List<NewsObjectsClass>> data)  {

        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);

        // Here i want to pass my List<List<NewsObjectClass>> to the bundle

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
...
```

So specifically i need a way how to pass my list of lsits of myCustomObjects to the fragment, so there I could use it for lsitview adapter.

Any syggestions on how to pass this type of data would be great. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your `NewObjectClass` `Parcelable` or `Serializable` and then create a new class, effectively, containing your list, also `Parcelable` or `Serializable`. Then use `Bundle.putSerializable` (or `putParcelable`)

Or, simpler, make `NewObjectClass` `Parcelable` then use `putParcelableArrayList` if you can do with `ArrayList` instead of generic `List`

Or, simplest, make `NewObjectClass` Serializable and use `putSerializable` passing `ArrayList<NewObjectClass>` because `ArrayList` is `Serializable`

In the last case perhaps you only will have to ad `implements` `Serializable` to your class.

Alternatively, if your data seem to be large, consider keeping them in a custom `Application`-derived object instead. You extend `Application` and then such object will exist all the time your app exist. Don't forget to register it in manifest.

```
class MyApplication extends Application {
   public static Object myData;
}
```

Or you can do with shared preferences

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().edit().putInt("a", 1).commit();
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences().getInt("a");
```

Comment: Is there a way doing this data-pass without serialization or so? Is this the only way?

Comment: If your class is simple enough you perhaps will only need to add implements Serializable then pass ArrayList to Bundle. Jsva takes care of serialization

Comment: @xenuit use Parcelable instead of Serializable, for more info see [this](http://blog.3pillarglobal.com/parcelable-vs-java-serialization-android-app-development)

Comment: Well, my class contains only String and Bitmap objects.
And one more thing - isnt it a problem of using List<List<CustomObj>> ?

Comment: Your data seem to be large. Consider keeping them in a custom Application-derived object instead. You extend Application and then such object will exist all the time your app exist. Don't forget to register it in manifest.

Comment: Those data are pretty large. Maybe i should consider of using database? Or that isnt a good way? (Have never used it before). And will it be possible to access those database data from everywhere?

Comment: @Alex If you go that route, be prepared for that data to go missing at any time after your application goes into the background. Preferably, store it persistently (e.g. in a SQLite database) and pass an identifier to the new Activity, allowing it to look up the data.

Comment: @xenuit From what I can see, a database definitely sounds like the proper solution for your data set.

Comment: If data a really large passing them in an Intent is not an option as it will freeze the application for a long time. Might be you can do with SharedPreferences instead of database they are easier

Comment: Well, thats an option, Alex. Seems that today I'll have a tutorial evening. Cus no doubt of how to use SharedPrefs, lol. =) Anyway, thanks for help.

Answer (score 21):

```
args.putParcelableArrayList(DATA_KEY, new ArrayList<>(data));
```

Answer (score 5):

use `putSerializable` method to pass your custom list.

```
args.putSerializable(KEY, ArrayList<Type>);
```

and fetch it using `getSerializable`

```
ArrayList<Type> list = (ArrayList<Type>) getArguments().getSerializable(KEY);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or, simplest, make NewObjectClass Serializable and use putSerializable passing ArrayList because ArrayList is Serializable

Unfortunately, this did not work in my case. I ended up converting my array list to string (or JSON string) and send by

```
bundle.putString()
```

and then, in fragment, parsed the string back to array list.